# Trace Plots after MCMC iteration with R2WinBUGS

Tags: plot, mcmc, bayesian-networks, r2winbugs

After carring a Network bayesian Meta-analysis with R2WinBUGS, I tried to create some plots. Specifically, i would like to carry out some trace plot figures to show model convergence; however, I can't create one and don't know how to do it.

Let's hypotize that i caonducted a NMA using bugs function saved this way:

```
res<- bugs(info, inits, parameters, model.file, n.chains=3, 
           n.iter=500000,debug=T, n.burnin=300000,n.thin=15, bugs.directory = "c:/WinBUGS14/",
           working.directory = NULL, DIC=T)
```

The best i could obtain was a traceplot with `mcmcplots::traceplot()`, but all three chains had the same colours.

Could anyone help me, please?